# how to add a "minimum number possible" using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

so i was creating a shop/store in my index html file. but i want to make that if i dont have enough gems, it wont let me buy the item
for example:

```
you can buy 1 coins from 20 gems
[Buy]
Gems: 19
Coins: 0
  Error: you do not have enough gems to buy a coin.
```

html:

```
<div id="gemplace">
                <div id="gems">
                    Balance: <span id="balance">0</span>
                </div>
                <div id="coins">
                    Coins: <span id="coins">0</span>
                </div>
                <div id="shop" style="background-color: black">
                    <div id="additem" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <button height="100" width="100" style="padding: 10px 14px" onclick="jsfAI()">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <h2 style="color: white">Recommended items</h2>
                    <div id="items">
                    <div class="class_built-in-item" name="coinsitem">
                    <img id="built-in-item-coins" src="icons&images/coins.png" height="90" width='100'>
                    <div class="cost">
                    <span class="cost_int">5</span>
                    <span id="currency"> gems </span>
                    <button onclick='buycoin()'>Buy</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The `buycoin()` function should compare the cost with the number of gems you have. If it's not enough, display the error message.

Comment: Ohhhhh i should if(gems > bal) { [Rest of function] } else {console.log("cannot")}

Comment: Exactly, it's as simple as that,

Comment: i was trying to find this for my game because i keep getting negatives no matter what i try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in javascript :

```js
< script >
  // Get references to the gems balance and coins
  const gems = document.querySelector('#balance');
const coins = document.querySelector('#coins');

// Get reference to the buy button
const buyButton = document.querySelector('button[onclick="buycoin()"]');

// Listen for a click on the buy button
buyButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Get the cost of the item
  const cost = parseInt(document.querySelector('.cost_int').textContent);

  // Check if the user has enough gems to buy the item
  if (parseInt(gems.textContent) >= cost) {
    // If the user has enough gems, subtract the cost of the item from the gems balance
    gems.textContent = parseInt(gems.textContent) - cost;

    // Increase the number of coins
    coins.textContent = parseInt(coins.textContent) + 1;
  } else {
    // If the user doesn't have enough gems, show an error message
    alert("Error: you do not have enough gems to buy a coin.");
  }
}); <
/script>
```